# Query Scheduling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, scheduler

I am trying to schedule a query in Google Cloud Platform query scheduler. But whenever I try to schedule, it is hardly executing. What I did is in steps below

```
1) Created a dataset with location US
2) Created a table in same location
3) Wrote a query
4) Scheduled a query . To check I gave the time to run in the next 3 minutes (not a cron type). Just added a scheduled time
```

But in the end, 1/10 times, it is executing as per the schedule. Rest, it is not even starting so I could log the error as well. Please advice

Comment: Did you see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries ? Check `Required permissions`, and `Configuration options` etc.

Comment: Not sure of the issue. But the CRON way of scheduling works properly

Comment: What were the values for Schedule options, such as the interval, the start time, end time? Did you set a custom interval, and if you did, what was the string you used? Other than that, do you see those jobs on the scheduled queries section? Or did you enable email notifications to get information for transfer run failures?

Comment: Yes Neri ...But CRON worked whereas the schedule date didnt work

Answer (score 0):

More clarification could be needed, but I see two possible situations:

1) You expected it to run on the exact time of the "Scheduled start time", but it doesn't work like this, it runs according to the schedule you set on the "repeats" dropdown. You can verify the exact scheduled time by going to "Scheduled queries" and then check "Next Scheduled"

2) If you set a custom schedule, did you consider that the time is UTC? You can also check the "Next Scheduled" time for what time would it be in your local time.